# Setting a fixed position to a DIV[not a footer or header] in jQuery Mobile doesn't work as intended

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am looking to set a fixed position to a div in jQuery Mobile,I know how to make it possible with the header by adding the data attribute data-position="fixed". What Im trying to achieve is to have fixed position for a DIV that is neither a header or footer,is this possible?

I thought I could achieve it using the code below,but it doesn't.The DIV doesnt even render

```
<div id="messageBox" data-position="fixed">
</div>
```

Comment: By my reading of the jQuery Mobile docs it does not appear that jQm supports this natively.  Have you tried straight up CSS?  position: abosolute; top: ##px;  ?  Would need to see more code to know if this was practical.

Comment: I'm already running into issues with iOS keyboard/input slide ups that are breaking my fixed footer... so if that's *already* an issue, I doubt you'll have much success position:fixed of a non-footer/header element.

Answer (score 0):

Currently only `<header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">` and `<footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">` are supported.

Since you want a `fixed` div, you probably know the distance from the top/bottom you want to fix it at.  Maybe you can use header/footer and hack the CSS to suit your needs by setting the margin in relationship to the top/bottom.